# How to check whether it is possible to obtain an increasing list by deleting one of its element in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

> what i want to do(python language):

I want to check whether it is possible to obtain a list by deleting one of its element such that the list is in increasing order .

e.g: for list = [1,2,4,3], it is POSSIBLE to obtain a list that is in increasing order by removing 4 .

. is there any way such that i can remove 1 number (temporary) and check whether:

```
sorted(list) == list
```

e.g: list = [1,2,4,3]

.1st i want to remove 1 and then check with [2,4,3]

.then i want to remove only 2 from list and check with list [1,4,3] and so on ..

**How can i do that in python;**

Comment: What about: `>>> lst = [1,2,4,3]
>>> del lst[2]
>>> lst == sorted(lst)
True` ?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar That's hard coded. OP probably wants something that can be used for all numeric lists.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar The problem with that is that we don't always know for sure that the item at the second index is the one that needs to be removed.

Comment: @ChristianDean Oh, I see, I misinterpreted the question then, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**`O(n)` algorithm:**

```
def almostSorted(L):
    """ function to check whether it is possible to obtain 
        a list by deleting one of its element such that 
        the list is in increasing order"""

    #uncomment the below line if you want to remain original list 
    #(in this case, func almostSorted(L) will work with copy of L) 
    #L = L[:]

    lenL = len(L)
    if lenL <= 2 :
        return True

    counter = 0
    while L[0] > L[1] and lenL != 1:
        del L[0]
        counter, lenL = counter+1, lenL-1

    i = 0
    while i+1 < lenL:
        if L[i+1] >= L[i]:
            i = i+1
            continue

        counter += 1

        if L[i+1] >= L[i-1]:
            del L[i]
        elif L[i+1] < L[i-1]:
            del L[i+1]
        lenL -= 1

    if counter > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Test 1:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
print L
print almostSorted(L)
print L

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Test 2:

```
L = [10,2,3,4,5]
print L
print almostSorted(L)
print L

[10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
True
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Test 3:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,1]
print L
print almostSorted(L)
print L

[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
True
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do like this:

```
def check(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        new_lst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        if sorted(new_lst) == new_lst:
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check([1, 2, 4, 3])) # True
    print(check([1, 2, 4, 3, 2])) # False
```

Comment: what does `if __name__ == '__main__' `mean

Comment: @SyedHissaan Come on, this at least can be googled easily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do.

Comment: complexity is `O(n^2)`, the algorithm is very slow for large n

Comment: Should'nt you return `True` if `len(lst) < 2` ?

Comment: @hivert I think raise a Exception may be better.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a copy of the list before doing `del list[x]` on any index. Lists are mutable and hence you will lose the original list once you delete any element from it.

You would need the original `list` to check all permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the list and try removing every element.

```
import copy

def is_increasing(sequence):
    sequence_n = copy.copy(sequence)
    for element in sequence:
        sequence_n.remove(element)
        if sorted(sequence_n) == sequence:
            return True
        sequence_n = copy.copy(sequence)
    return False
```

Comment: `sorted(sequence_n) == sequence` is always false.